# What is the true concept behind the band ghost?

Tags: rock, bands

I came across the band “Ghost” recently. Their melodies and riffs are amazing. I am trying to learn more about them. 
I have seen many interviews for them and in many of those ones they emphasize that they are not a satanic band and it’s really up to the listener to interpret it the way they want it.

This is a Q/A from one of the interviews,

> You’ve been called an “anti-Pope” band and “Satanic.” Is that accurate?
>   I think that depends completely on which level of intellect you’re bringing to your theological discussion. Obviously from a Biblical blind person, we would be deemed as utterly satanic. I guess we are for that person. But from an intellectual point of view, with a slightly broader philosophical angle, I think we’re really not. But who are we to say? At the end of the day, we’re an entertainment act. That doesn’t mean that everything we’re saying is bullshit, but that means that we are here to entertain people.

Read more at https://www.phillymag.com/ticket/2015/09/26/interview-ghost-pope-francis/#KILWoMZJQt45JIc7.99

What confuses me is the lyrics of some songs I.e Year Zero, which I really can’t comprehend what is the message behind it.

The question is, what is really the concept behind this band? Are they all about satan or there is more to it?

Comment: Ii don't understand your question... it seem you provided yourself a quote and a link that has the answer.

Comment: No, because I was hoping that someone with more experience with this band can provide more insights. The Q/A and the the link just makes me more confused. If they are not satan advocates why their lyrics sounds and read like one?

Comment: You are looking for a source more reliable than the band itself? The interview you quoted is from a member of the band.

Comment: How do you see the band from your perspective ? I am assuming that you are a fan